# Get NSAttributedString from UITextView with UITextRange

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, ios7, nsattributedstring

How do I get an `NSAttributedString` from a `UITextView` from a specified `UITextRange`? I can't seem to find any examples or documented resources on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found it:

```
- (id)attribute:(NSString *)attributeName atIndex:(NSUInteger)index effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)aRange
```

Comment: can you add code in comment pls how it work. I need to use attributedstring in my textview for different objects : title, detailtitle and other.

Comment: @user2545330 You can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:). It is very well explained there.